# postgresql get timestamp column as zonedatetime

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I want to take a postgresql table record of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE` using Spring-Boot's `JdbcTemplate`.

I got the below error while fetching timestamp column as Java 8's `ZonedDateTime` i.e (`queryForObject(myQuery, ZonedDateTime.class)`)

> Type mismatch affecting row number 0 and column type 'timestamptz':
>
> Value [2018-06-26 18:19:31.313733] is of type [java.sql.Timestamp] and
>
> Cannot be converted to required type [java.time.ZonedDateTime]

How to solve this?

Comment: The output given for `timestamptz` looks like it doesn't have a timezone, but `ZonedDateTime` requires one (I assume). If you try `queryForObject(myQuery, LocalDate.class)` or `queryForObject(myQuery, Date.class)` then it will probably work. If timezone is essential you will need to update the column type and update the values to include timezone.